# Before save actions - dynamodb-data-mapper

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently struggling with `dynamodb-data-mapper` and `dynamodb-data-mapper-annotation`.

I have a class corresponding to a table and some of the attributes must be recomputed every time we save an object.

I've been able to use `marshall` and `unmarshall` for the `updatedAt` attribute as it's completly independant, but when I need an interaction between several of them I cannot find any successful workaround.

I would like this be something totally internal and a method that I would have to call (better to avoid mistakes later).

Can you see any solution ?

```js
@table('my-class-table')
export class MyClass {
  @autoGeneratedHashKey()
  readonly id: string;

  @attribute({ defaultProvider: () => new Date() })
  readonly createdAt: Date;

  @attribute({
    type: 'Custom',
    defaultProvider: () => new Date(),
    marshall: (): AttributeValue => ({ S: new Date().toISOString() }),
    unmarshall: (persistedValue: AttributeValue): Date => new Date(persistedValue.S!),
  })
  readonly updatedAt: Date = new Date();

  @attribute()
  alerts: VehicleAlert[];

  // This attribute depends on the alerts attribute
  @attribute()
  status: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your exact use-case (and maybe you already figured it out), but I solved a similar problem by using a getter. For your updatedAt example:

```
class MyClass {
  get updatedAt() {
    return new Date().toISOString();
  }
}
```

The data mapper will access the property every time you save the document, and it will update the record in the database with the value it gets from the getter.